# Mysql duplicate primary key error - but key does not exist in db

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert multiple rows into the database. Out of 23,000 insert statements, ~600 are failing in this manner:

example query:

```
INSERT INTO authorization_codes (book_id, auth_code, unpaid) 
(SELECT edition_nid,'FLT9950526', 1 
 FROM catapult.editions WHERE isbn_digital = '978-1-4533-2704-3');
```

error message:

> [ERROR in query 2800] Duplicate entry 'FLT9950526' for key 'PRIMARY'

The primary key in this case is '`auth_code`'

```
select * from authorization_codes where auth_code = 'FLT9950526';
```

this returns no rows.

More clues- in the script I am running with multiple insert statements, the errors happen consecutively in the file.

When I take the query out of the script- it errors the same way, with a duplicate entry error.

What am I doing to cause this?

(edit- sorry, cut & paste error, grabbed wrong error row, thanks @juergen-d)

Comment: FLT9950526 != FLT9150367

Comment: Is it possible the data you are inserting contains the same `auth_code` in multiple records?

Comment: Hi @DCoder- in that case, I would end up with a row at the end.... but no, I did check that. 



`1 match for "'FLT9950526'" in buffer: codes.sql 5600:edition_nid,'FLT9950526', 1 FROM catapult.editions WHERE isbn_digital = '978-1-4533-2704-3');`

Comment: @Slabgorb . . . How many rows are returned by the query `SELECT edition_nid,'FLT9950526', 1 FROM catapult.editions WHERE isbn_digital = '978-1-4533-2704-3'`?  My guess is that multiple rows in the `editions` table are being returned.

Comment: You got it @Gordon-Linoff, thanks! Want to put that into an official answer so I can accept it? That also explains the sequence thing, as I am inserting rows ordered by isbn_digital.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is:

```
INSERT INTO authorization_codes(book_id, auth_code, unpaid) 
    SELECT edition_nid, 'FLT9950526', 1 
    FROM catapult.editions
    WHERE isbn_digital = '978-1-4533-2704-3';
```

This single statement is inserting one or more rows from `editions` into `authorization_codes`.  If more than one row has the given `isbn` in `editions`, then query will attempt to insert multiple rows with the same `auth_code`, resulting in a violation of the uniqueness constraint.

Because of the way that SQL works, either all the rows are inserted or none of them.

To be safe, you can do:

```
INSERT INTO authorization_codes(book_id, auth_code, unpaid) 
    SELECT edition_nid, 'FLT9950526', 1 
    FROM catapult.editions
    WHERE isbn_digital = '978-1-4533-2704-3'
    limit 1;
```

(This inserts one arbitrary row.)

Or you can change your script to do something like this so duplicates are never inserted:

```
INSERT INTO authorization_codes(book_id, auth_code, unpaid) 
    SELECT edition_nid, 'FLT9950526', 1 
    FROM catapult.editions
    WHERE isbn_digital = '978-1-4533-2704-3' and
          1 = (select count(*) from catapult.editions where isbn_digital = '978-1-4533-2704-3');
```